# How to create a summary report showing outbound data going through the firewall (iptables)

Tags: iptables

I have installed fwlogwatch and generate a daily report like this:

```
fwlogwatch -b -l 1d -N -n -M 20 -w -T infrastructure@mydomain.com /var/log/kern.log /var/log/syslog
```

It doesn't seem to correlate with my nginx access logs and seems to report much less traffic in terms of bytes. So I am not sure I really trust it.

But what I really want is two reports: the first like this showing incoming traffic and the second showing the amount of outgoing traffic.

Note, I run a lot of services as docker containers so it would be cool to have the outgoing traffic grouped by source ip address of those containers.

How can I create such a report?

Answer (score 0):

One choice is

```
iptables -xvn -L OUPUT
```

Choice 2 ipset and iptables

Even more complexities are possible including logging both the source and destination ip addresses are possible with this method just not shown here.

```
ipset create output hash:net counters
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -j SET  --add-set output dst
iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -m set --match-set output dst
```

You can substitute **src** for **dst** if you want source data instead.

Alternatively to monitor INPUT:

```
ipset create INPUT hash:net counters
iptables -I INPUT 1 -j SET  --add-set INPUT src
iptables -I INPUT 1 -m set --match-set INPUT src
```

Some packets may actually use the FORWARD group

```
ipset create FORWARD hash:net counters
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -j SET  --add-set FORWARD src
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -m set --match-set FORWARD src
```

Then use

```
ipset save
```

to view the results.

Also if you only can about certain ip addresses you can remove "--add-set".  Then manually populate the list.

```
ipset add input 192.168.0.1/24
ipset add input 192.168.1.1/24
ipset add input 192.168.2.1/24

ipset add output 192.168.0.1/24
```

If you do manually populate the list you are going to want to then use:

```
ipset save >ipset.txt
```

and later

```
ipset restore <ipset.txt
```

The ALL sets and configuration options including counter will all be save and restore all at once unless you configure it otherwise.

Additionally, you can

```
ipset save >daily.txt
ipset flush
```

After the flush you can restore a master list of ip address with their counters all set at 0 in the master list.

```
ipset restore <all-sets-at-zero.txt
```

This will flush ip address by not the groups.  Thus reseting all counters to 0.  You would create a cron job to **save** and then **flush** the sets daily for daily reporting.

Choice 3 iptables with ULOG

iptables -I OUTPUT 1 ULOG options

Then you can modify the ulogd.conf file to log virtually anywhere even a database.